# Skills and tennis surface?

Tags: tennis, technique

How can a tennis player use his skills in his favor on the different surfaces of play?

I mean

- Is a powerful player favourite on grass/hard/clay ?
- Is a technical player favourite on grass/hard/clay ?
- Is a quick player favourite on grass/hard/clay ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the properties of the surfaces :

- Hard surfaces are fast and there are no big effects on the rebounds, so they're great for quick and powerful players
- Clay is a slow surface, where you can set serious effects on the rebounds, which is perfect for technical players
- Grass surfaces are the fastest ones and they're great for quick players, since the ball rebounds lower, the receiver must be very quick.

Answer (score -1):

It actually depends on the players' comfort area. A technical player can adapt to any surface.

Comment: Welcome to Sports.SE. If you elaborate on your answer it might be more useful to general audience. For instance what do you mean by _comfort area_, why/how does it affect a player?